# blender get object from position

Tags: game-engine, blender

I have seen many questions asked on how to get the position of an object, but I need the opposite. I am making a game and know there is one object at a certain  owner.worldPosition, and I need to get the object's game properties. How could this be done? Also, please use code and not logic bricks.

Answer (score 0):

You use a python controller to run your script. The owner that you get from

```
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner
```

is the object that is running the script. Note that a [game object](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html) does not have the same properties as the object you get through `bpy`.

If you want to access other objects, you can access them through the object list in the [game scene](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_Scene.html).

```
sce = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
for ob in sce.objects:
    print("   ", ob.name, ob.worldPosition)

print(sce['otherObj'].worldPosition)
```